# How to save corrupt map service back to Service Definition (*.sd) file?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, map-service

I have a corrupt ArcGIS Server Install and don't want reconfigure the existing services.

I understand that one can take a *service definition* file (.sd) and [publish it as a map service on ArcGIS Server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Publishing_a_service_definition_to_the_server_in_Manager/01540000043p000000/).

**Is there a way to save a map service back to a .sd file?** Basically Map Service TO SD File

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the ArcGIS Server go to the folder `<installpath>/usr/directories/arcgissystem/arcgisinput/<map service name>.MapServer/extracted/v101/` (Note this is for Linux, I imagine the Windows path is similar)

This should contain the .mxd and .msd and data used to publish the service. You can copy these files back to your PC and re-package them into a .sd file.

Comment: nice thanks.  This should probably do it.  Looks like a good thing to script out.  Thanks for your help